# Refering to other entities when using Linq2Sql and Sprocs

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

We are evaluation Linq2Sql for internal applications, and our development guidelines mean that we must always use stored procedures for all CRUD operations, from various blogs i have got together an application that does much of what we want.

However, what i would like to do is when we have a relationship between two entities the relationship can be fulfilled automatically.

For example if i had an instance of a Person object I would like to be able to say

var absenceCount = persons.Absence.Count()

but because we do not have select permission on the Absence table we get a Sql exception.

is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By sheer chance I came across a couple of blog posts which prove this is possible, I have tested it and it works a treat

basically having methods called Load calling into your stored proc added into your DataContext class will allow this to work

links with examples here

[Damien Guard](http://damieng.com/blog/2010/01/11/linq-to-sql-tips-and-tricks-3)

[Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546186.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

By using stored procedures for all of your database operations, you lose most of the benefits of an ORM like Linq-To-SQL and using LINQ queries. For example, by using stored procedures to retrieve all your data, you lose the ability to have strong type checking on all your queries.

You can of course still use L2S with stored procedures, but I don't really see the point in it if all your query operations must be done via stored procedures.

To answer your second question, how do you expect L2S to be able to populate the Absence table if you don't have permission to do a Select against the table? If L2S were somehow able to do this, what would be the point of the security you have established?

Randy

Comment: My understanding was that when you dropped the select stored procedure onto the table in the designer, that became the select for the table( despite how inefficient that maybe) I guess that's not the case

Comment: Yes but you are still just using L2S to execute a stored procedure to retrieve data. L2S isn't really providing any value here, and you still don't have strong type checking on your queries.

Comment: There is obvious benefit with using L2S in that it generates a DAL and creates the mapping and a UOW the only missing problem we have is that entityref's cannot be read.

Comment: Actually, this is completely possible, see my answer below

Comment: This answer doesn't answer the question, it merely suggests changing the way the person works. A lot of us work in large organisations that are set in their ways and changing from stored procedure to select access requires more time and energy than turning the largest of oil tankers.